# Sort Hibernate @OneToMany via related property?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

In my schema I have a tables `Cutter`, `Property`, and `PropertyValue`. Partial columns:

```
Cutter
  id

Property
  id
  name
  desc

PropertyValue
  property_id
  cutter_id
  value
```

I want to do something like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Cutter")
public
class
Cutter implements Serializable
{
    @OrderBy("property.name asc")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cutter") protected SortedSet<PropertyValue>      properties;
}
```

But that results in the obvious exception: `Unknown column 'properties0_.property.name' in 'order clause'`.

I made `PropertyValue` implement `Comparable`, but that doesn't seem to be enough. Hibernate wanted the `@OrderBy` annotation anyway.

Comment: is `name` a property of `PropertyValue`? If yes, just use `@OrderBy("name asc")`

Comment: @jorgegm, sorry if that wasn't clear, but no, `name` is a property of `Property`, which is why this isn't straightforward.

Comment: ops, i didn't noticed it. According to OrderBy's javadoc it isn't possible: "The property or field name must correspond to that of a persistent property or field of the associated class or embedded class within it.". One posible solution is to use a `List<PropertyValue>` and implement a `@PostLoad` method to build the  `SortedSet`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `Comparable` and annotate the `SortedSet` property with `@Sort(type = SortType.NATURAL)` allowing Hibernate to sort it in memory.

Comment: I found `@org.hibernate.annotations.SortNatural`, which seems to give me the behavior I want, although I don't know what kind of performance impact this will have. Fortunately, there are only a handful of properties per `Cutter`. Thank you!

Comment: If you ever find yourself querying a number of `Cutter` instances of which you may need to access those property values, you can also use `@BatchSize` to minimize the N+1 select overhead.  Obviously it'd be ideal to have the database perform the sort but just keep an eye on it and profile to be sure.